# What happens if I override an abstract void method with async?

Tags: c#, async-await, abstract

As in the title, I am overriding `abstract void` method with `override async void`, but I'm not sure what will happen when the method is called via the base class as I can't put an `await` there.
Will the thread hang until the task is completed, or behave as if an `await` was there?

I already found by other answers that I should use `Task` as return value to make all the code clearer, but I want to know if there are also behavioral differences.

Some code for clarity:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
     public abstract void Method();
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
     public override async void Method()
     {
           await Task.Run(() => SomethingLong());
     }
}

class Caller
{
     public void CallingMethod()
     {
          BaseClass bc = ...;
          bc.Method();
          //What happens here? The task will be fully waited,
          //or the rest of this method will be appended as continuation?

          /*Other code*/
     }
}
```

Comment: If you won't await anything, then the `async` keyword won't do anything.

Comment: I am awaiting inside the overriding method

Comment: then it will await as expected.

Comment: And what about the caller?

Comment: Please provide an example, because I'm not sure what the exact problem is.

Comment: Since the method returns `void` nothing that calls the method, base class included, can `await` the completion. Your free to `await` within an `async void` method but nothing can `await` the call to it.

Comment: Basically you're producing a method that will return immediately, if its implementation is not blocking, and the calling method will immediately execute the code following the call to the overridden method. The method and its side effects, since it's `void`, have become fire and forget. That means that caller cannot depend on the completion of that method, i.e. cannot not depend on whatever that method was intended to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to know. I can accept it if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method returns `void` nothing that calls the method, base class included, can `await` the completion. You're free to `await` within an `async void` method but nothing can `await` the call to it.

Basically you're producing a method that will return immediately, if its implementation is not blocking, and the calling method will immediately execute the code following the call to the overridden method. The method and its side effects, since it's `void`, have become fire and forget. That means that caller cannot depend on the completion of that method, i.e. cannot not depend on whatever that method was intended to accomplish.

Note: this answer was provided through comments. I'm writing this for posterity and the `answered` mark.